# getting error in jfree chart , getting null vaue from xyplot (what can be return by xyplot and dateaxis method)

Tags: jfreechart

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.Users.np.JFreeChart.getXYPlot()" because "this.chart" is null
at com.Users.np.NewMain.loop(NewMain.java:277)
at com.Users.np.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:132)

Comment: Please describe your code instead of giving the error.

Comment: public DateAxis getDomainAxis() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
return null;
   
  }        -> returning null beacuse of this , what can be returned by this method?

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.